# Optimizing MySQL select query

Tags: mysql

**MySQL version:** 5.7.23
**Engine:** InnoDB

I created an application that monitors network devices from around the world with ICMP echo request packets. It pings devices on a regular interval and stores the results in a MySQL table.
I have a query that fetches the latest 100 up/down events for a given device, but it takes ~38 seconds to execute, which is way too long. I'm trying to optimize the query but I'm kind of lost.

The query:

```
select
    c.id as clusterId,
    c.name as cluster,
    m.id as machineId,
    m.label as machine,
    h.id as pingResultId,
    h.timePinged as `timestamp`,
    h.status
from pinger_history h
join pinger_history_updown ud on ud.pingResultId = h.id
join pinger_machine_ip_addresses i on h.machineIpId = i.id
join pinger_machines m on i.machineId = m.id
join pinger_clusters c on m.clusterId = c.id
where h.deviceId = ?
order by h.id desc
limit 100
```

Explain query output:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+------------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                | key     | key_len | ref                       | rows   | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+------------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ud    | NULL       | index  | PRIMARY                      | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL                      | 111239 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | h     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,deviceId,machineIpId | PRIMARY | 4       | dashboard.ud.pingResultId |      1 |     5.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | i     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,machineId            | PRIMARY | 4       | dashboard.h.machineIpId   |      1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,clusterId            | PRIMARY | 4       | dashboard.i.machineId     |      1 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                      | PRIMARY | 4       | dashboard.m.clusterId     |      1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+------------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

The pinger_history table consists of around **483,750,000 rows** and pinger_history_updown around **115,520 rows**. The other tables are small in comparison (less than 300 rows).

If anyone has experience in optimizing queries or debugging bottlenecks then all help will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

I added the missing `order by h.id desc` to the query and I made pinger_history the first table in the query.

Here are the create table queries for pinger_history and pinger_history_updown:

**pinger_history:**

```
mysql> show create table pinger_history;
+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table          | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| pinger_history | CREATE TABLE `pinger_history` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `deviceId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `machineIpId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `minRoundTripTime` decimal(6,1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `maxRoundTripTime` decimal(6,1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `averageRoundTripTime` decimal(6,1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `packetLossRatio` decimal(3,2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `timePinged` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('Up','Unstable','Down') DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstOppositeStatusPingResultId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `deviceId` (`deviceId`),
  KEY `machineIpId` (`machineIpId`),
  KEY `timePinged` (`timePinged`),
  KEY `firstOppositeStatusPingResultId` (`firstOppositeStatusPingResultId`),
  CONSTRAINT `pinger_history_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`machineIpId`) REFERENCES `pinger_machine_ip_addresses` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `pinger_history_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`deviceId`) REFERENCES `pinger_devices` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `pinger_history_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`firstOppositeStatusPingResultId`) REFERENCES `pinger_history` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=483833283 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**pinger_history_updown:**

```
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                 | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| pinger_history_updown | CREATE TABLE `pinger_history_updown` (
  `pingResultId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `notified` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pingResultId`),
  CONSTRAINT `pinger_history_updown_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`pingResultId`) REFERENCES `pinger_history` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Edit 2:**

Here is the output of `show index` for pinger_history:

```
mysql> show index from pinger_history;
+----------------+------------+---------------------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table          | Non_unique | Key_name                        | Seq_in_index | Column_name                     | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------------+------------+---------------------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| pinger_history |          0 | PRIMARY                         |            1 | id                              | A         |   443760800 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| pinger_history |          1 | deviceId                        |            1 | deviceId                        | A         |      288388 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| pinger_history |          1 | machineIpId                     |            1 | machineIpId                     | A         |       71598 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| pinger_history |          1 | timePinged                      |            1 | timePinged                      | A         |    38041236 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| pinger_history |          1 | firstOppositeStatusPingResultId |            1 | firstOppositeStatusPingResultId | A         |        8973 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------------+------------+---------------------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

**Edit 3:**

Here is the explain output when I add straight_join:

Note that the query takes almost 2 minutes with straight_join but around 36 seconds without.

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+------------------------------+----------+---------+-------------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                | key      | key_len | ref                     | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+------------------------------+----------+---------+-------------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | h     | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,deviceId,machineIpId | deviceId | 4       | const                   | 344062 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ud    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                      | PRIMARY  | 4       | dashboard.h.id          |      1 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | i     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,machineId            | PRIMARY  | 4       | dashboard.h.machineIpId |      1 |   100.00 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,clusterId            | PRIMARY  | 4       | dashboard.i.machineId   |      1 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                      | PRIMARY  | 4       | dashboard.m.clusterId   |      1 |   100.00 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+------------------------------+----------+---------+-------------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: add a multi column index on the table columns and see if that can help

Comment: Make pinger_history the base table you are querying. Even though it has more records assuming that deviceId is index it will use that over table scanning. you can also create a composite index on deviceId and pingResultId which will help with that join

Comment: Please post DDL...

Comment: Good execution plan woud put `pinger_history` table first and use index on `deviceId` field.  Is `deviceId` indexed?

Comment: @SteveMapes I made pinger_history the base table and now the query explain output no longer reads `using temporary` or `using filesort` which I think is a step in the right direction! but the query still takes around the same time to complete.

@Naktibalda I believe `deviceId` is indexed. When I execute `show create table pinger_history` then it shows `KEY deviceId (deviceId)` and `CONSTRAINT pinger_history_ibfk_4 FOREIGN KEY (deviceId) REFERENCES pinger_devices (id) ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Comment: @NevilleKuyt I've added the DDL for pinger_history and pinger_history_updown.

Comment: I was wrong. The explain output for the query still outputs `using temporary` and `using filesort`.

Comment: I would create a composite index on columns id, machineIpId and deviceId on pinger_history. You're using those in order by/joins/where clauses

Answer (score 0):

create index on following columns

```
pingResultId ,machineIpId ,clusterId .pinger_clusters .id,
pinger_machine_ip_addresses.id,pinger_history.id,pinger_machines.id,deviceId ,
pinger_history_updown.pingResultId
```

indexing will reduce the time taken to fetch the data

Comment: Make it clear that you are calling for "composite" (multi-column) indexes, not single-column indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the "STRAIGHT_JOIN" keyword and also put the pinger_history into the first position.  Then, include an index on pinger_history by the DeviceID to optimize the WHERE clause.  Your other tables would probably already have an index on their respective ID keys implied and should be good.  The STRAIGHT_JOIN clause tells MySQL to run the query in the table/join order I gave you, don't imply something else.

```
select STRAIGHT_JOIN
      c.id as clusterId,
      c.name as cluster,
      m.id as machineId,
      m.label as machine,
      h.id as pingResultId,
      h.timePinged as `timestamp`,
      h.status
   from 
      pinger_history h 
         join pinger_history_updown ud
            on h.id = ud.pingResultId
         join pinger_machine_ip_addresses i 
            on h.machineIpId = i.id
               join pinger_machines m 
                  on i.machineId = m.id
                  join pinger_clusters c 
                     on m.clusterId = c.id
   where 
      h.deviceId = ?
   order by
      h.id desc
   limit 100
```

Since you DO want the most recent records, I would definitely have and index on your pinger_history table on (DeviceID, ID ) -- change your existing key of DeviceID only and change it to (DeviceID, ID)

This way, the WHERE clause is FIRST optimized to get the Device ID records.  By having the ID as part of the index, but in the second position, the ORDER by can utilize that to get the most recent first for you.

Comment: I've moved pinger_history to the first position now, but I messed up when I pasted the query in the OP. It actually has `order by h.id desc` to get the latest rows instead of the oldest ones.

Comment: @HallurA., revised message to include the order by, and suggested index to help optimize.  My query as written should work for you.

Comment: I order to change the deviceId key I'd have to drop it and then recreate it as a composite key (deviceId, id). The problem is that deviceId is needed in a foreign key constraint, so in order to drop it I have to drop the foreign key. Is that wise?

Comment: @HallurA., I would just add a secondary index by the composite key then.

Comment: I added the composite key and tried adding straight_join to the query but it still takes 2 minutes 11 seconds. `mysql> create index deviceId_id on pinger_history(deviceId, id); Query OK, 0 rows affected (42 min 28.42 sec) Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0`

Comment: The query execution time also increased from ~36 seconds to ~50 seconds when I leave out the straight_join.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that your query fetches the latest 100 events for device, but there is no ORDER BY clause in your SQL.

Add `ORDER BY h.id DESC`to your query and create composite index on (devideId, id) fields.

Comment: Ohh you're right! The query actually has `order by h.id desc` but I messed up when I created the post. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE pinger_history` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE pinger_history_updown` would be usefor for optimisation advice too.

Comment: I've added the create table queries for the tables you mentioned.

Comment: Try to use STRAIGHT_JOIN now and see how it affects execution plan.

Comment: Done. I added it to the bottom of the OP. The query takes almost 2 minutes when using straight_join, but only ~36 seconds without it.

Comment: Have you really got approximately 344062 records per device?

Comment: 483,858,126 records and 2,515 devices, so around 192,618 records per device. The service has been running for about 1 year, 7 months.

Comment: That's a lot of data, probably this is the best you can get from that query without taking a different approach like creating a summary table or moving old data to archive table.

Comment: (In InnoDB, the PK is implicitly added to each secondary key.  So, technically, you already have `INDEX(deviceid, id)`.)

Comment: @Naktibalda - The 344062 is just Explain making a poor estimate; it has no impact.

Comment: @rickJames impact is 2 minute execution time, I would expect it to take a fraction of second if it used that index and limit optization as expected

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Get rid of `pinger_history_updown` and move `notified` into `pinger_history`.  Perhaps augment `status` to indicate "CameUp" and "WentDown".  Pro: That will make the query much faster since it will be able to use `INDEX(deviceId)`.  Con:  It makes `pinger_history a little bigger`; adding columns to a huge table will take time.

Plan B:  Add `deviceId` to `pinger_history_updown` and have `INDEX(deviceID, pingResultId)`.  Pro:  Much faster query.  Con:  Redundant data (`deviceid`) is frowned on.

<strike>Plan C:  Add an index hint to force the execution to start with `pinger_history`.  Con: "What helps today may hurt tomorrow."</strike> (`STRAIGHT_JOIN` was tested and found to be slower.)

Plan D:  See if `ANALYZE TABLE` for each table will help.  Pro:  Quick and cheap.  Con: May not help.

Plan E:  Change to `ORDER BY deviceId DESC, id DESC`.  Pro:  Cheap and easy to try.  Con: May not help.

Plan F:  In `pinger_history`, change

```
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `deviceId` (`deviceId`),
```

to

```
      PRIMARY KEY(deviceId, id),
      KEY(id)
```

This will make the desired rows "clustered" much better.  Pros:  Much faster.  Con:  `ALTER TABLE` will take a long time for that huge table.

Plan G:  Assume it is an explode-implode problem and move the `LIMIT` into a derived table:

```
select  c.id as clusterId, c.name as cluster, m.id as machineId,
        m.label as machine, h2.id as pingResultId, h2.timePinged as `timestamp`,
        h2.status
    FROM  
    (        -- "derived table"
        SELECT  ud1.pingResultId
            FROM  pinger_history_updown AS ud1
            JOIN  pinger_history AS h1  ON ud1.pingResultId = h1.id
            WHERE  h1.deviceId = ?
            ORDER BY  ud1.pingResultId
            LIMIT  100    -- only needed here
    ) AS ud2
    JOIN  pinger_history AS h2  ON ud2.pingResultId = h2.id
    join  pinger_machine_ip_addresses i  ON h.machineIpId = i.id
    join  pinger_machines m  ON i.machineId = m.id
    join  pinger_clusters c  ON m.clusterId = c.id
    order by  h2.id desc   -- Yes, this is repeated
```

Pro:  May make better use of 'covering' `INDEX(deviceId)`, especially if merged with Plan B.

Summary:  Start with D and E.